# WebStorm 2016.2.3 does not recognise *ngFor in html tag

Tags: angular, webstorm

I am taking my first steps using Angular 2 and I am experiencing a strange behaviour in WebStorm as shown below. It expects for a newline or something for some reason.

[image: Sintax problem WebStorm Angular]

Everything is **working fine** on the browser side, but WebStorm remains complaining. Am I missing something? Please, find below my WebStorm specs.

- WebStorm 2016.2.3
- Build #WS-162.1812.21, built on September 4, 2016
- Subscription is active until October 2, 2017
- For educational use only.
- JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-b343 x86_64
- JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are using a very old version/guide of angular2. The template syntax has changed for a while now. To do a [**for loop**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngFor) you have to use the `let` keyword:

```
<tr *ngFor="let product of products"></tr>
```

For the latest documentation and quickstart, best way to start is at [angular.io](https://angular.io/)

Comment: [this article](http://jilles.me/ng-repeat-in-angular2-ng-for/) led me in the wrong direction too - so many outdated resources for Angular2 using old syntaxes. Need a mass cull!